# How to disable clickjacking in new universal login page in auth0

Tags: auth0, clickjacking

I have application which renders auth0 login in an iframe using classic universal page.
However, I want to switch to new universal login page but want to disable clicjacking feature.

Is there any way to disable clickjacking in new universal login page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as per [Auth0 documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/troubleshoot/product-lifecycle/past-migrations/clickjacking-protection-for-universal-login)

in the **classic flow**:
set the following HTTP headers

`X-Frame-Options: deny Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'`

in the **new universal flow**:

> The following action is not required if you are using the New Universal Login Experience because those headers are always set in that case

Comment: Hi Akber, that is what, in new universal login page 'Clickjacking protection' is enabled by default and there is no way to disable it.. I have confirmed this with Auth0 support team recently. Thanks